# mysql jamed after add record from other table

Tags: mysql

i have a issue  with  mysql

i have 4 tables  i created view from  : cots total form

```
    SELECT
    `Table`.ItemID,
    Details.Material,
    Material.Categoryid,
    Details.`Usage`,
    uc.uc * Details.`Usage` /0.95 AS Cost,
    ((SELECT cost))/0.9 AS NET_Cost,
    ((SELECT NET_Cost))/0.9 AS SST,
    ((SELECT SST))/0.85 AS Local_Price
    FROM Details
    INNER JOIN Material ON Details.Material = Material.Material
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Category ON Material.Categoryid = Category.CATEGORYID
    INNER JOIN `Table` ON Details.ItemID = `Table`.ItemID
    , uc

WHERE (`Table`.REMARK = 'cost')
```

other view form name is UC

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Material,
    Material_Name,
    Grand_Cost,
    uc,
    w1,
    w2,
    w3
FROM uc
```

it worked fine  if i open " uC" view but other view every time i add uc.uc inside first view it jam  "uc.uc * Details.`Usage` /0.95 AS Cost,"

what could be wrong  ? any help  is highly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "jammed"?

Comment: once i run  the 1rst view " cost " it took  more than 20 min with no result which is weird  this happened only if i call uc columns from view uc

Answer (score 0):

Move the condition into the join:

```
SELECT
    `Table`.ItemID,
    Details.Material,
    Material.Categoryid,
    Details.`Usage`,
    uc.uc * Details.`Usage` /0.95 AS Cost,
    ((SELECT cost))/0.9 AS NET_Cost,
    ((SELECT NET_Cost))/0.9 AS SST,
    ((SELECT SST))/0.85 AS Local_Price
    FROM Details
    INNER JOIN Material ON Details.Material = Material.Material
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Category ON Material.Categoryid = Category.CATEGORYID
    INNER JOIN `Table` ON Details.ItemID = `Table`.ItemID
        AND `Table`.REMARK = 'cost'
    , uc
```

Also, can you replace `, uc` with a proper join?

Comment: thank u for ur answer  , im noob to this  how to join view  ? as i know can join  table  but view how to do ?be cause UC column is a  calculated field

Comment: @AliIm you join views the same as tables, but did my change to your query fix the problem?

Comment: unfortunately not working  . i get another way by using  ALTER TABLE Statement   to get calculated column inside table  . tqvm

Comment: whats not working was the call of view uc.uc  the  alter table  fix the issue , problem here now is cannot be auto generated  fewww tired thing